# .alx file mime type

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

can any one tell me what the is mime type of .alx file ?

Comment: text/xml or application/xml? I don't think it has anything specific if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it would be `application/octet-stream` [from](http://www.filesuffix.com/extension/alx.html) I personally would stick with this as a posed to `application/xml` because I wouldn't want browsers to render it but rather for the browser to simply download it and put it in a folder some where nice and tidy for the bb-tools to use.

That being said you do not download a .alx file to a blackberry you download it to your desktop and use it via the blackberry tools to install the application.

Comment: Does this mean ALX files are not meant for OTA installs?

Comment: @Jahufar yes it does. You need to use a Jad file for that.